# How to specify Arbitrary data type when defining flink sql function

Tags: apache-flink

I want to define a function that will compute object's hash code, the code is as follows.

```
class HashCodeFunction2 extends ScalarFunction {
  def eval(s: Object): Int = {
    if (s == null) 0 else s.hashCode()
  }
}
```

but when I use it,flink throws the followings error message, I would ask how to fix it, thanks.

`Cannot extract a data type from a pure 'java.lang.Object' class. Usually, this indicates that class information is missing or got lost. Please specify a more concrete class or treat it as a RAW type.`